# Is activity launch intent data secure?

Tags: android, security, android-intent

I noticed that with logcat I can see ActivityManager logs when my Activities are being launched. Does anyone know if it is safe to pass around sensitive information as intent data (for things like authentication tokens, API tokens etc..)? Or can this be intercepted by any other apps installed on the device?

Comment: [Old versions of Android (2011 and older) definitely leaked `Intent` extras](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/30/warning-activity-intent-extras-public.html) through `ActivityManager`. I forget when they locked that down, but nowadays you should not be able to access those extras from third parties. That being said, I would recommend erring on the side of caution, and if both activities are in the same app and process, don't pass those tokens around via extras. Use something in-process, like a singleton authentication manager, that both activities can access.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Could you add this as an answer so I can select it (for posterity)? BTW with regard to using a singleton manager, this wouldn't this survive an app restart would it?

Comment: "Could you add this as an answer" -- well, since I don't recall exactly when they locked it down (and that's important info) I would recommend leaving this open until somebody who has that info handy can link to it. "this wouldn't this survive an app restart would it?" -- it won't survive process termination. If tokens need to live longer than that, you need to persist them anyway, as if the user clears the task, you won't get the value back via the extras. In that case, you treat the persistent store as the system of record, with an in-process cache (probably in the form of that singleton).